# [Boost].DI decorator pattern

Tags: c++, boost

Is it possible to create decorator pattern with [Boost].DI library?

```
struct IFoo {};
struct Foo : IFoo { };

struct Decorator : IFoo
{
    explicit Decorator(shared_ptr<IFoo> foo) : foo(foo) {}

    shared_ptr<IFoo> foo;
};

auto injector = boost::di::make_injector(???);
```

How to setup injector so that injector.create() returns a valid instance of Decorator?

Answer (score 1):

I found solution using annotated constructor injection and named parameters, but there may be a more elegant solution that I am missing.

```
auto decoratee = [] {};

namespace boost {
    namespace di {
        template<>
        struct ctor_traits<Decorator>
        {
            BOOST_DI_INJECT_TRAITS((named = decoratee) std::shared_ptr<IFoo>);
        };
    }
}

namespace di = boost::di;

auto injector = di::make_injector(
    di::bind<IFoo>().named(decoratee).to<Foo>(),
    di::bind<IFoo>().to<Decorator>());
```